# $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ is uncountable

Tags: number-theory

I am trying to show that the set of $p$-adic numbers $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ is uncountable. I have that $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ is uncountable (which clearly then means that $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ is too). But how do I show that $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ is uncountable in the first place?

Comment: You might also look at  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1583418/finding-an-example-of-a-non-rational-p-adic-number/1583451#1583451

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just apply Cantor's diagonal method to show that $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is uncountable, representing a $p$-adic integer as $b_0+b_1p+b_2p^2+\cdots$.
For a reference see Corollary 3.5. [here](http://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~evertse/dio2011-padic.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

The set of expansions $\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_ip^i$, with $0\leq a_i<p$ is uncountable. The proof is literally the same as the proof that the interval $[0,1]$ is uncountable. Have a look into Cantor's second diagonalization method.

Comment: @Glorfindel - just a quick comment: I don't think one should say that the proof is 'literally' the same - it is easier. Namely, for the reals, one has the possibility of two distinct decimal expansions, e.g, $0.1= 0.0\overline{9}$ - that doesn't happen in the $p$-adics.

Comment: @peterag I just corrected a problem with the source code of the answer. I haven't studied it in detail.